# Delete or ignore index python

Tags: python, indexing

I'm trying to separate or not take index in array.

```
best = result_df.sort_values(by=['result'], ascending=False)[:1]
best.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
print(best)
```

```
  period  window  no_of_std    result
0    12H    77.0        1.0  0.191576
```

I need to take all the values as integer to use in following function

```
  simulator = BollingerBandsSimulator(
      df, 
      from_date="2015-05-01", 
      period= best.period, #"12H"
      window= best.window, #77
      no_of_std=best.no_of_std #1
  )
  simulator.simulate()
```

I get error 'window must be an integer' . How can I fix this?

Comment: looks like window is a float...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please provide a complete reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions, but it depends on what you have control over. Perhaps the easiest is to simply cast `best.window` to an integer in the call to `BollingerBandsSimulator`.

```py
  simulator = BollingerBandsSimulator(
      df, 
      from_date = "2015-05-01", 
      period = best.period, #"12H"
      window = int(best.window), #77    <==== CAST AS INTEGER HERE
      no_of_std=best.no_of_std #1
  )
  simulator.simulate()
```

Or use the `astype` method in pandas. This will keep it as a pandas series. This would be better if your simulator is expecting a series. Your other parameters don't seem to be having issues with the pd series.

```py
window = best.window.astype('int'), #77
```

Another way is to clean the data first. You can change the type of the column in pandas like this:

```py
best = result_df.sort_values(by=['result'], ascending=False)[:1]
best.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
best = best.astype({'window': 'int32'}  # 'int' would work here too
print(best)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because best.window is a pd.Series object, while you are wondering it is a integer (77).

It's because best is a dataframe with one row (but still a dataframe), so best.window is a pd.Serie (with one value, but still a Serie). You can fix it just doing window=int(best.window[0]) (cast window to integer), period=best.period[0] and no_of_std=best.no_of_std[0].

It should be like this:

```
best = result_df.sort_values(by=['result'], ascending=False)[:1]  # this is a pd.DataFrame
best.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

simulator = BollingerBandsSimulator(
      df, 
      from_date="2015-05-01", 
      period= best.period[0], #"12H"
      window= int(best.window[0]), #77
      no_of_std=best.no_of_std[0] #1
  )
```

Alternatively, you could fix it keeping the parameters of BollingerBandsSimulator as they are, but changing the definition of best (to be a pd.Series instead of a dataframe).
It should be something like this:

```
best = result_df.sort_values(by=['result'], ascending=False).iloc[0]  # this is a pd.Series
simulator = BollingerBandsSimulator(
      df, 
      from_date="2015-05-01", 
      period= best.period, #"12H"
      window= int(best.window), #77
      no_of_std=best.no_of_std #1
  )
```